# VBA Syntax finding the last occupied cell in the column

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

How do I make this work? I'm trying to make the code identify the last used cell in column C and go to it. I am having trouble with the last part which is selecting the cell in rng1

```
Sub jupiter3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("Belmont")
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("c").Find("*", ws.[c1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "last cell is " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
Else
    MsgBox ws.Name & " columns A:B are empty", vbCritical
End If
Range("rng1.address(0, 0)").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way for me would be to use this one line of code

```
Sheets("Belmont").Range("C" & Sheets("Belmont").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

but if you want to modify yours then

```
Sub jupiter3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Belmont")
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns("c").Find("*", ws.[c1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "last cell is " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
        rng1.Select
    Else
        MsgBox ws.Name & " columns A:B are empty", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Changing `Range("rng1.address(0, 0)").Select` to `rng1.Select` or `Range(rng1.address).Select`

Answer (score 0):

The rng1 variable is defined as a range which is interpreted by the language in a way in which it doesn't fit into range().select You want to define a string variable and do it like this.
replace *Range("rng.address(0,0)").Select* with

```
Dim zen as String
zen=rng.address(0,0)
range(zen).select
```